# strange issue with aliases for zsh

Tags: command-line, ssh, zsh, alias

I'm trying to create an alias in my `.zshrc` file for an SSH connection. The full command is this:

```shell
ssh -t pi@raspi5 "cd ~/C-progs/c_trials; exec \$SHELL -l"
```

The command is designed to open an SSH connection, `cd` to a chosen directory, and then start a login shell. I can execute this command perfectly well from the command line of `Terminal`, and it does exactly what it's supposed to do.

The command is a bit to remember, so I decided to create an alias for it. I put the alias in `~/.zshrc`:

```
alias sshrp5="ssh -t pi@raspberrypi5 "cd ~/C-progs/c_trials; exec \$SHELL -l""
```

Which is, IIUC, the *prescribed* way to create an alias under `zsh`. Unfortunately, `zsh` apparently does not like this alias:

```shell
source ~/.zshrc
```

`source`ing `~/.zshrc` with the above alias in it immediately closes the `Terminal` tab from which I attempted the `source` command!!  Fortunately, I had 3 tabs open, otherwise I would have been **locked out** of `Terminal`!!

Anybody know what I've done to offend the great and powerful `zsh`? :)

Comment: In your alias, the opening quote after `sshrp5=` is closed right in front of the `cd`. Later on, there is a semicolon which terminates the `alias` command, and this is followed by an `exec` command which replaces your shell by a new process.

Comment: The `terminal` tag doesn’t fit here, please read the tag description.

Answer (score 1):

Double quoting is tricky. In your case, Zsh sees the end of the quoted part before the `cd` and the alias definition ends with the `;`, so `zsh` sees *two* commands on one line here:

```sh
-- 1st command --------------------------------------------  -- 2nd command --
alias sshrp5="ssh -t pi@raspberrypi5 "cd ~/C-progs/c_trials; exec \$SHELL -l""
```

When sourcing `.zshrc`, the shell defines the alias as `ssh -t pi@raspberrypi5 cd ~/C-progs/c_trials` and then tries to execute `exec \$SHELL -l`. As the `$` is quoted, the binary to execute is literally called `$SHELL` (which obviously fails because there is no such binary usually). A failing `exec` can't be recovered from, so you get kicked out of the shell.

```sh
$ zsh
% alias sshrp5="ssh -t pi@raspberrypi5 "cd ~/C-progs/c_trials; exec \$SHELL -l""
zsh: command not found: $SHELL
$
```

I usually use shell functions when I need aliases with complex quoting needs.

Comment: uh... the stuff in the *inner* dbl quotes is `bash`.

Comment: @Seamus There are no inner double quotes for the zsh parser, the quoted part ends before the `cd`, followed by an unquoted part up to the final `""` (which basically is a no-op). Also, while the line gets parsed/executed, you are always in zsh, bash doesn't play a role here.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. The solution was simple, but *baffling*:

```
alias sshrp5='ssh -t pi@raspberrypi5 "cd ~/C-progs/c_trials; exec \$SHELL -l"'
```

IOW, I simply replaced the outermost double-quotes with single-quotes, and it worked. I ***thought*** I had tried single-quotes first, but maybe I had something else wrong??

Anyway - this Question and Answer hardly seem worth leaving up. It *might* help someone else, but I'll look for guidance from the mods on whether or not to delete.

Comment: Ah come on, I now wasted/spend way to much time analyzing why zsh behaves as it does. Let's leave it up :-)

Comment: PS: Actually, quoting issues are common, so there is even value to keep it (besides my obvious bias here).